# ASP.NET API serialize entities with circular dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization

I've got `Test` entities and `User` entities.

Test:

```
public class Test
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Title {get; set;}
  ...
  public virtual IList<User> Users {get; set;}
}
```

User:

```
public class User
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  ...
  public virtual IList<Test> Tests {get; set;}
}
```

Within my `TestsApiController` I have the following action:

```
public IQueryable<Test> GetTests()
{
    return db.Tests;
}
```

This returns a serialization exception because it attempts to circularly serialize the `User` objects then their `Test` objects then their `User` objects and so on.

My current plan is to create a `TestDTO` which contains a `IList<int> UserIds` rather than the actual objects. Then I will have to convert all the `Test` objects into `TestDTO` object before serialization which is somewhat annoying. And then if I ever want to serialize other entities with circular dependencies I will have to create more Data Transfer Objects for them.

Is there a way to create or configure a serializer to automatically serialize `User` (or any other) objects in this context to simply their `Id` property?

**EDIT WITH EXCEPTION:**
I get the same exception whether using `XML` or `JSON`

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Test_6585C5F85A384907958ABA03B661933EF718BDEDE1513392E060DE06E80DB552' with data contract name 'Test_6585C5F85A384907958ABA03B661933EF718BDEDE1513392E060DE06E80DB552:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>...</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</Error>
```

Comment: I would say the issue here is the design, not the serializer. Consider if `Test`s really need a list of `User`s. If so, I would store a list of IDs instead of the actual objects.

Comment: Well this is all using Entity Framework. The fact that it stores the `User` objects rather than their `Id`s is very useful elsewhere in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a very easy way to construct your json result is to use a JObject from the NewtonSoft json serializer (which is usually the default in ASP.NET Web Api). What you are looking for will look something like

```
public JObject GetTests()
{

    NewtonSoft.Json.Linq.JObject jsonResult = NewtonSoft.Json.Linq.JObject.FromObject(new 
    {
        Tests = from test in db.tests
                select new 
                {
                    Id = test.Id,
                    Title = test.Title,
                    Users = from user in test.Users
                            select new
                            {
                                Id = user.Id
                            }
                }
    });

    return jsonResult;
}
```

This gives you more control over your json result so you can choose what fields/properties you want to serialize and avoid creating a lot of Data Transfer objects. Hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: I would not consider this much better than just creating a `TestDTO` since you are basically creating the same thing as an anonymous type.

Comment: I think this is more convenient because if you create a TestDTO, you'll have to do some sort of mapping between your POCO and and the DTO. But with a JObject you can just choose what properties you wanna serialize quickly and easily.

Answer (score 1):

In your web api config (App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs), add this:

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
      public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
      {
        // Prevent "Self referencing loop detected" error occurring for recursive objects
        var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        };
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = serializerSettings;
      }
    }
```

This tells JSON.NET to ignore nested objects referring back to the parent object

Comment: I just did that and i still get the same exception. I edited my question to include it.